# Is it possible to upload only files that have been updated into a server?

Tags: ftp, automation, upload

Suppose I have a server accessible via FTP and it hosts websites

Suppose I want to edit the website locally so it wont affect the site live, and suppose I edit a whole bunch of files, and I don't want to deal with the hassle of keeping track of which files I've edited all the time...

Once I finished editing I want to upload it to the server via FTP....is there some FTP software that automatically detects which files have been edited and have only those files uploaded and overwritten rather than having me manually choosing the files I've edited (and hence having to keep track of edited files) or have me upload the entire site which is a waste of time

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many FTP clients are capable of synchronizing file trees based on file sizes or modification date. One solution would be [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). On the Mac, I use the (commercial) program [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/), and I love it.

If you have access to the server via SSH beside FTP and want to use the command line, [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) would be the canonical solution.

Comment: +1 for using SSH and rsync. Even if you find another solution rather than rsync, you should look at moving off using FTP in general because it's an insecure protocol. Once you're using SSH/SFTP, your problem is solved by rsync too, which is an added bonus :)

Answer (score 0):

I write [a wee program](http://pushsite.sourceforge.net/) to do exactly this some time ago. However its rather sensitive to variations in message formats for different clients and servers - the [docs](http://pushsite.sourceforge.net/readme.html#if) include links to other products available at that time which do a similar job.

HTH